# C - Passing a pointer as a pointer to another function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

So, I have one function like the following:

```
void myfunction1(int *number)
{
    ...
}
```

And I have:

```
void myfunction2(int *number)
{
    ...
    myfunction1(&number);
}
```

When I run the code I get the error:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘myfunction1’ from incompatible pointer type
```

So I changed my second function to:

```
void myfunction2(int *number)
{
    ...
    myfunction1(&(*number));
}
```

And I got:

```
dev(887) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd400403810: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Any ideas?

Comment: just `myfunction1(number);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number` already has type `int*` so you can pass it directly to `myfunction1` with `myfunction1(number)`. The `malloc` error has nothing to do with any code that you have shown.

Answer (score 2):

Number is already a pointer to int. Therefore if you do `&number` where number is an `int*` you are passing a pointer to a pointer to int.

```
void myfunction2(int *number)
{
    myfunction1(number);
}
```

will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

basically what the others are saying is this is what you should do:

```
void myfunction2(int *number)
{
    ...
    myfunction1(number);
}
```

inside myfunction2, number is already a pointer, so pass that as it is to myfunction1